# Configure new installed WordPress in live server

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hosting

I've just installed Wordpress from my cPanel with Hostgator and this is my dilemma:

My static html site was hosted here at `www.mydomain.com` and I  installed Wordpress in same path. I am able to login into my dashboard and activate new themes but when I  click visit website that takes me to same html version and not my Wordpress site. How do I configure my site so that instead of loading my old html site it, it will take me to WordPress site instead. if I remove  files for html site, will it automatically render my new WordPress site or do I need to do extra configuration for this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your static html site probably has an index.html file, and your WordPress install has an index.php script. Since you installed WordPress in the same folder as your static site both will now exist in the same folder.

The default configuration for Apache is when you browse to the doc root or a directory Apache will look for index.html first and if not found then look for index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

In your case index.html is found and served.

If you remove or rename index.html you should see your WordPress install since Apache will then look for index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Name of the old file or if you are not going to use it.Just get rid of it.